# How to tackle changing properties on the clientside in GWT applications?

Tags: gwt, configuration, build, properties

while developing GWT apps we ran into lots of problems with project configuration. Let me explain... As usual in development, we have few environments for our application: local, demo, preview and live. Of course they are running on different machines, some are using SSL while others don't. But most importantly - all of them have different URLs.

Now, in few places in our application we need specify some URLs. Usually we would use *.properties files stored on server, and tools like Spring taglibs and it's `<spring:message />` tag. But since GWT does not have such tools, we ended up in leaving hard coded URLs and performing code replacement on different SVN branches. As you can imagine - this is the worst possible scenario, causing us much problems.

**So, my question is:**
how one could build proper, flexible mechanism of storing config properties shared for both client and server side in GWT application. This properties have to be available for server-side handlers, client app (compiled JavaScript), UiBinder, other code running on server (workers, Spring, etc.).

The preferred way would be to avoid **gwtc build** if we change value of some property, but I guess it will be hard to achieve. So I will accept any reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using relative URI references (e.g. absolute paths, without scheme or authority; i.e. `/path/to/foo` instead of `http://example.com/path/to/foo`)?

And in the few places where you absolutely need an URI (with scheme and authority), then use another property to store the "prefix" (e.g. `http://example.com`), and then concatenate with the above path.
Those places where you need a full URI should all be on the server, which means you don't have to recompile your GWT project when you change the "prefix", so everything is only runtime configuration and you can deploy the same artifacts in all environments.

That being said, if you ever need something configurable at runtime in GWT, then use a dynamic host page and JSNI (or a `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Dictionary`); see http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/dynamic_host_page.html

Comment: And how about if the URL I want to redirect to (Window.location=) does not belong to my webapp (it might be external payment service)? Different environments will use different payments URLS as well. Your idea is fairly good but it helps only with URLs within my webapp, and very often configuration aims for external systems.

Comment: In that case, then follow the last advice: put the value in the HTML host page (a dynamic host page allows you to read it from a properties file, but a static host page would work too) and read it using JSNI or a `Dictionary` from your GWT app.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into JSNI and Dictionary class. Thanks for the tip! If I decide that satisfies my needs, I will mark the question as answered.